Aandroid app crash -> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_object == null
### Description

I am getting multiple crash reports related to this package in the Google Play console report

### Steps to reproduce

Use reanimated 2.14.4 and build the Android dev app

### Snack or a link to a repository

null

### Reanimated version

^2.14.4

### React Native version

0.70.6

### Platforms

Android(10/11/12/13/14)

Error trace
backtrace:
#00  pc 0x000000000009ce10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
#01  pc 0x000000000076fc20  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+904)
#02  pc 0x00000000000357d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_0::__invoke(char const*)+80)
#03  pc 0x0000000000034d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+352)
#04  pc 0x00000000003eb64c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+3540)
#05  pc 0x000000000055e818  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallLongMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+380)
#06  pc 0x000000000029d654  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (_JNIEnv::CallLongMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+188) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#07  pc 0x000000000029d44c  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::JMethod<long ()>::operator()(facebook::jni::alias_ref<_jobject*>) const+100) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#08  pc 0x000000000029d2f4  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_6::operator()() const+212) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#09  pc 0x00000000002bfed4  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14::operator()(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>) const+176) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#10  pc 0x00000000002bfd70  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (decltype(std::__ndk1::forward<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14&>(fp)(std::__ndk1::forward<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>>(fp0), std::__ndk1::forward<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>>(fp0))) std::__ndk1::__invoke<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>>(reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&)+108) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#11  pc 0x00000000002bfc80  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (void std::__ndk1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>>(reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&)+84) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#12  pc 0x00000000002bfc00  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (std::__ndk1::__function::__alloc_func<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14, std::__ndk1::allocator<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14>, void (std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>)>::operator()(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&)+84) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#13  pc 0x00000000002bdad0  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (std::__ndk1::__function::__func<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14, std::__ndk1::allocator<reanimated::NativeProxy::installJSIBindings()::$_14>, void (std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>)>::operator()(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&)+84) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#14  pc 0x00000000002d2784  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (std::__ndk1::__function::__value_func<void (std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>)>::operator()(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>&&) const+116) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#15  pc 0x00000000002d2530  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (std::__ndk1::function<void (std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>)>::operator()(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>) const+88) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#16  pc 0x00000000002d216c  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (reanimated::EventHandler::receiveEvent(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>)+292) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#17  pc 0x00000000002d17c4  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::EventHandler::)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>), &reanimated::EventHandler::receiveEvent(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>), reanimated::EventHandler, void, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>&&, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>&&)+264) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#18  pc 0x00000000002d18b8  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::CallWithJniConversions<void ()(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>&&, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>&&), void, facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>>::call(facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, _jstring*, facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::react::WritableMap, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void ()(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>&&, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>&&))+148) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#19  pc 0x00000000002d15f8  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::FunctionWrapper<void ()(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>&&, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>&&), facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jstring*, facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::react::WritableMap, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void ()(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::EventHandler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>&&, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>&&))+72) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#20  pc 0x00000000002d1584  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::EventHandler::)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>), &reanimated::EventHandler::receiveEvent(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>), reanimated::EventHandler, void, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::JString>, facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::react::WritableMap>>::call(_JNIEnv, _jobject*, _jstring*, facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::react::WritableMap, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*)+68) (BuildId: 19b42179ac26405d7145408427a4bcb97213811d)
#21  pc 0x0000000000080550  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+144)
#22  pc 0x00000000005b98b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+4016)
#23  pc 0x0000000001876bfe  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.reanimated.NativeProxy$EventHandler.receiveEvent+46)
#24  pc 0x00000000005ba674  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
#25  pc 0x000000000188b2f6  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.events.ScreenWillAppearEvent.dispatch+34)
#26  pc 0x00000000005b9854  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#27  pc 0x0000000001878146  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.handleEvent+70)
#28  pc 0x00000000005b9854  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#29  pc 0x0000000001878378  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.onEventDispatch+12)
#30  pc 0x00000000005ba674  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
#31  pc 0x0000000000b92aba  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl.dispatchEvent+54)
#32  pc 0x00000000005ba674  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
#33  pc 0x0000000001883f06  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.dispatchEvent+238)
#34  pc 0x00000000005b9854  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#35  pc 0x0000000001884098  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.dispatchOnWillAppear+4)
#36  pc 0x00000000005b9854  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#37  pc 0x0000000001884202  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.dispatchViewAnimationEvent$lambda-8+22)
#38  pc 0x00000000005b8934  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52)
#39  pc 0x0000000001883d44  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment.$r8$lambda$acfFq_XavoVj9P4B8s6sdtwvx2c)
#40  pc 0x00000000005b8934  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52)
#41  pc 0x000000000188384c  /data/app/~~csMhyoVzA1_Jx7fR59no4w==/org.mentortogether.mentorship-oXTCBbAA62D_L5OsR8q2yQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run+8)
#42  pc 0x0000000000b0067c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+76)
#43  pc 0x0000000000b07a50  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+1408)
#44  pc 0x0000000000b0741c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1196)
#45  pc 0x00000000008349c4  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+2532)
#46  pc 0x000000000033b680  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+640)
#47  pc 0x000000000037cb18  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1556)
#48  pc 0x000000000037c4f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) (.__uniq.165753521025965369065708152063621506277)+32)
#49  pc 0x000000000039e6a8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+120)
#50  pc 0x0000000000d3f464  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+132)
#51  pc 0x0000000000d4cfa0  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+4880)
#52  pc 0x000000000033b680  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+640)
#53  pc 0x00000000004e2a90  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+728)
#54  pc 0x000000000057aa68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+156)
#55  pc 0x00000000000e2be8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+108)
#56  pc 0x00000000000ef40c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+936)
#57  pc 0x00000000000026a8  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1616)
#58  pc 0x00000000000955f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
